# Canon LBP2900 printer only works when connected after log in

Tags: printing, canon

I have a Canon LBP2900 printer and Ubuntu Natty 64-bit.

After quite some trouble I found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) a nice guide explaining a installation procedure with packages from [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon).

I followed the guide and did all steps and now the printer works if it is connected (or powered on) after login.

If I connect it already before my computer is started, the following happens. A second printer (LBP2900-2) is automatically created and the command `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status` only gives one pid, while it should give two.

How can I fix this?

An extra detail that can help; normally the device uri is `ccp:/var/ccpd/fifo0`. Actually this path (/var/ccpd/fifo0) does  not exist, but that does not seem to matter. The printer that Ubuntu automatically adds when starting up with the printer connected has `usb://Canon/LBP2900` as uri

The output of `grep lp /etc/udev/rules.d/*`:

```
~$ grep lp /etc/udev/rules.d/*
/etc/udev/rules.d/85-canon-capt.rules:KERNEL=="lp*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04a9", RUN+="/bin/bash /etc/init.d/ccpd start"
/etc/udev/rules.d/85-canon-capt.rules:KERNEL=="lp*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/bash /etc/init.d/ccpd stop"
```

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @jrg since going to 11.10 I have other problems: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79906/installing-lbp-2900-printer-libs-folders-wrong

Comment: So this question is no longer relevant?

Comment: @jrg Maybe not for me, but probably for others.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like udev is somehow confused.  I suggest double-checking your steps on that page under the heading [Starting/Stopping on USB Add/Remove](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190#Starting/stopping%20on%20USB%20add/Remove).  Assuming that is all correct, add the output of the following command to your question:

```
grep lp /etc/udev/rules.d/*
```

Comment: See my addition. I have done all steps outlined in the guide to the letter.

Comment: Hrmph.  I was hoping maybe there would be some other lp* related rules that were causing problems.  I'm sorry, I don't know what else to suggest.