# Installing LBP 2900 printer -> libs folders wrong?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, printing, canon

I am trying to get my Canon LBP2900 printer to work on Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit.

What I have done is try to follow the steps on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190

So I downloaded the version 2.3 driver and tried to convert the rpm files to debian and installed them

```
sudo alien cndrvcups-capt-2.30-1.x86_64.rpm cndrvcups-common-2.30-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt-2.30-1.x86_64.deb cndrvcups-common-2.30-1.x86_64.deb
```

restarted cups and try to install the printer with lpadmin:

```
sudo service cups restart
sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m /usr/share/cups/model/CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E
```

What I noticed however that on the step with lpadmin it goes wrong with the error:

```
lpadmin: Bad device-uri scheme "ccp"
```

After trying to trace what has gone wrong, I think I nailed it to the fact that dpkg installed a file `/usr/lib64/cups/backend/ccp` instead of `/usr/lib/cups/backend/ccp`

Checking the original rpm with archive manager shows indeed that `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64` are used, with the backend/cpp file only installed in lib64. As I understand correctly, Ubuntu 11.10 uses `/usr/lib32` and `/usr/lib` instead so the files are installed in the wrong place.

Is there an automated method of converting the rpm/deb files with the wrong lib structure to one with the right lib structure for ubuntu 11.10? Or am I completely on the wrong track for getting my printer installed?

Comment: can you confirm in your question whether the bug report for oneiric at the bottom of that link is applicable to your printer type?

Comment: @fossfreedom I did the modprobe to get that module to load, that part is working. The problem is really with the wrong installation directories I think...

Comment: I cant answer about "an automated method" - I dont think it is possible. However, if the code was expecting stuff in one folder then you can symbolic link from one folder to another i.e `ln -s target linkname` e.g. `ln -s /usr/lib64/cups/backend/ccp /usr/lib/cups/backend/ccp`

Comment: Same question asked (still unanswered), for **Karmic 64bit**, at: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8434976

Comment: Does your **ccpd** file have the same content as this (example): http://pastebin.com/bsQ95E3z AND does the section "DevicePath /dev/usb/lp0" match your device location?

Comment: I have followed the link, which has worked for me ...

http://askubuntu.com/questions/383695/installing-canon-lbp2900b-over-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 4):

> What I noticed however that on the step with lpadmin it goes wrong with the error:
>   lpadmin: Bad device-uri scheme "ccp"

It is because you didn't generated the scripts associated with the rpm files.......

Use

> sudo alien cndrvcups-capt-2.30-1.x86_64.rpm cndrvcups-common-2.30-1.x86_64.rpm --scripts

OR

> sudo alien *.rpm --scripts

instead of

> sudo alien *.rpm

You can solve this error

> lpadmin: Bad device-uri scheme "ccp"

All the best from RJK

Comment: @PeterSmit : If this problemis solved... you can mark it as solved :) It may help others too

Answer (score -1):

I do not own this particular model from Canon but i never find any trouble when installing a new printer on my system, also Canon declares this driver as working under all the latest versions of Ubuntu and many other GNU/linux distribution.

http://software.canon-europe.com/

Here you can download driver for both 32 and 64 bit operative systems, also there are the source included in the package so you can build your own driver from the scratch.

Do not use the rpm as first resource especially on a deb based system.

to find out what libreries are used by a specific executable run this command

```
ldd [path to exec]
```

Sometimes there are scripts available to start the program and they are not executables, to find out where the real executable is located you have no choice other than investigate the source of the script.

For example to know which libraries are used by `java` you can use `ldd` combined with `which` that is a command that gives you the full path of an keyword command ( only `which` works for both scripts and exec, `ldd` need an exec ):

```
ldd $(which java)
```

I suggest to completely remove those installed packages and compile from the source, if you can't remove those packages safely try to do something with `ldd` and verify that all the required libraries are linked to your executables, you can also run this command `sudo apt-get install -f` to try to fix some missing packages.

EDIT: i almost forgot this, to update all the linking between the libraries and the executable you have to run `sudo ldconfig` and this is useful after you have installed new libraries.

Apparently there are good links with this search http://www.google.com/search?q=compile+cndrvcups-common and some good ppa too.

Comment: Could you indicate: 1) Where Canon declares the driver to be working, and 2) Where Canon has published a 64-bit deb file of the CAPT driver.

The problem is not that libraries are not linked well, but that the cpp protocol file is installed on the wrong location. The ppa you indicated in your search is not working for Oneiric.

Comment: 1) at the page where you can find the download link for your package 2) I didn't say that, i didn't mention the deb, you can compile from the source if you wish or use a ppa ( where you can also downloade the deb "manually" if you like ) 3) https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon?field.series_filter=oneiric or http://www.google.com/#q=ppa+canon+capt if you wish :)

Comment: 1) http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/Laser/Laser_Shot_LBP2900.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:14-823414&page=1&type=download says nothing about whether the driver is working for the latest Ubuntu version 2) if you say driver for 32bit 64bit or source package, but not the rpm, than you imply there is a 64bit deb. 3) As I indicated now, that PPA is not working

Comment: i think that the real problem is your installation, installing an rpm is one of the best way to corrupt your system, i can't think that the ppa it's not really working simply because it does and i checked.

Comment: I didn't install an rpm, but an with alien to deb converted rpm. Why if the ppa is working is putted in this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190 different instructions for 11.10? I will later today check the ppa again, and see what went wrong there for me.

Comment: because that ppa is granted to work under Oneiric 11.10 and i do not think that a community resource is more reliable than a ppa or launchpad. Investigate your problem with ldd to check for libraries and links, i speak for my expierence, using an rpm under a deb based machine it's a really dangerous thing if you do not know what are you really doing.

Comment: When I now look the the ppa link you gave I see the problem, no canon driver packages are published for Oneiric!

Comment: I gave you the bounty as you have tried to help me, thanks for that! I however still haven't found a solution regrettably.